# Issues passing an variable to constructor

Tags: java, variables

I have the following variable

```
double x = 0.03D;
```

After I pass it to a constructor

```
private double rememberVar;
public constructor(double x) {
    this.rememberVar = x*2;
}
```

I want to use it in another function(inside the same class) which gets as argument a double.

```
this.setAttribute(maxHealthAttr).setValue(this.rememberVar);
```

The problem that I have is the following: rememberVar will not be used as 0.06D, but as 0.06

It is for the first time I actually use a variable of this kind and I do not know how to operate on it, or if I actually chose the double type correctly.

[I tried (in the constructor) converting the rememberVar variable to String, add a "D" at the end then convert it back to double with no success.](https://gist.github.com/05211ce3a45e3d8ccbda)

Comment: "The problem that I have is the following: rememberVar will not be used as 0.06D, but as 0.06" - what do you mean by that? The D is just a suffix on the literal to show that you want it to be a `double`. It's not part of the value.

Comment: Note that in the code you've linked to (which should be in the question), your constructor parameter is an `int`, not a `double`... and you never set the value of `x`.

Comment: @JonSkeet so if i would use 0.06 in that function it will work as well as 0.06D? -------- + edit: The code i've linked was just a simple test that did not work,it had double at first

Comment: Yes. They're both just `double` literals. Your question is very, very unclear at the moment, in terms of what you're trying to achieve and what's going wrong.

Comment: @JonSkeet I am trying to achieve sending 0.06D as parameter to a specific function instead of 0.06

Comment: To make it short: 0.06 is the same as 0.06D.

Comment: The "D" only tells the compiler explicitly, that this is a double. But 0.06 is already clearly a double, so D is totally useless here. D doesn't become part of the value, it's just a hint how to interpret the value. `1` would be an int, `1D` is a double - and the same as `1.0`. If you write `0.06D`, you only create a double with the value 0.06. That's all. Same as if you created one with `0.06`.

Comment: Thanks, i finally understood.

Comment: Or to put it another way - if you think they're different, how would you be able to tell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suffix `D` just indicates that the number you assigned to the variable `x` is a `double`. This shouldn't be necessary as `x` already is of type `double`.

Franky, I never use the suffix `D` to typecast to `double` since, in your case, `0.03` already is of type `double` and not of type `float`. If you explicitly want a `float`, use `0.03f`.

Your `rememberVar` doesn't have the `D` suffix because that suffix isn't actually part of the number, it's just used to typecast.

Comment: I'm thinking hard but finding no good reason to use `D` at all. If I wanted to write 1 as a double, I would probably type `1.0` instead of `1D`.

Comment: Exactly what I'd use as well.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is any problem or issue in your implementation. D is used as a suffix to indicate that the variable operation should follow double datatype's rules.

0.06 in your case is 0.06D as the data type is of double type.

In case you want the variable to follow some other datatypes rules you can add suffix or cast it into a different datatype(float, int etc)